# How to populate specific cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

How can I populate specific cells with value of the highest total.

[image]

So the table in the image shows a restaurant column and 3 score columns. I want to be able to populate top 3 with the 3 restaurants with the highest score. How can I achieve this?

Comment: All total showing 0. Put table image with data.

Comment: added the data @Harun24HR

Answer (score 0):

You can try following.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$50,MATCH(LARGE($E$2:$E$50,ROW(1:1)),$E$2:$E$50,0))
```

Put above formula under `Top3` cell then drag and drop down.

Comment: it repeated Mr Kim's twice

Comment: Can you explain what will happen in case of duplicate total?

Comment: list the duplicate totals as well.